# How to allow execution and creation of files on a filesystem mounted to /mnt

Tags: root-access, mount

I have a rooted device with Android 11 (LineageOS) and Termux. With root permission an app (that's EDS for crypto containers but should not matter) mounts an ext4 file system to `/mnt/eds/Data`.

The mount options for `Data` seems to include a flag that determines the SELinux context and could be problematic: `context=u:object_r:fuse:s0`.

That `Data` directory and all its parents, for testing, have read and execute permissions for others and also write permissions. I have also tried to set respective permissions for the owner group such that the Termux user is part of that group `everybody`.

For some reason, I cannot create files in `Data`, nor can I execute files as the default Termux user. I can also not create files with file manager apps, although I can read and write existing files. It may be noteworthy that I can execute and create as `su` with Termux.

Something prevents it for the regular users. I found that on my device `/mnt` is mounted with options `noexec,mode=755`, but remounting with `exec,mode=777` has not changed the behaviour.

Since I do not want to further escalate the permissions, I would like to avoid running the binaries I want to execute with `sudo`. Therefore, how can I get the permissions to execute and create files in `Data` when the filesystem permissions appear to allow that?